# How can I add a ViewPager to a Navigation Drawer Item in Android application?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to add a viewPager for main fragment in my android app.

This is the xml file for main fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Java code for Main Fragment

```
public class MainFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private StudentsDBHandler studentsDBHandler;

    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        studentsDBHandler = new StudentsDBHandler(getActivity());
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        displayStudents();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void displayStudents() {
        List<Student> studentList = studentsDBHandler.getAll();
        ArrayAdapter<Student> list = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.item_student, studentList);
        setListAdapter(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a DrawerLayout page. It's about your drawer contains. 
İn the `DrawerLayout XML`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

add this code below

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

write this code and setup your `View pager` like example

```
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fm));


    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {



            if(position==0)
                fragment= new Home1();




            if(position==1)
                fragment=new Home2();
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

}
```

I hope Help you